# memory usage keeps going up when repeating requests

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, backend

Recently I'm writing a database webserver and I have some problems about the django's working machanism. I have a function in my view.py like this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def general_plot_strip(request,gene_name,format = 'image/png'):
    pl = GenePlot(gene_name)
    if request.method == "GET":
        ### here stripplot() is a plot function
        fig = pl.stripplot()
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        fig.savefig(buf, format='png')
        plt.close('all')
        buf.seek(0)
        gc.collect()
        return FileResponse(buf, content_type='image/png')
```

This can run smoothly when running `python manage.py runserver`, but when I request the corresponding url for serveral times, the memory usage just goes up and never drops.
This is an example when I try to request the url twice.

[image: Initial status]

[image: first request]

[image: second request]

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a context manager 'with' statement.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def general_plot_strip(request,gene_name,format = 'image/png'):
    pl = GenePlot(gene_name)
    if request.method == "GET":
        fig = pl.stripplot()
        with io.BytesIO() as buf:
          fig.savefig(buf, format='png')
          plt.clf() # clear the current figure...
          plt.close('all')
          buf.seek(0)
          gc.collect()
          return FileResponse(buf, content_type='image/png')
```

Comment: I am sorry,but I receive the same error as Pierre's code-.- maybe django don't support to close buf like this?

Comment: The django shell returned: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Comment: can you try response= HttpResponse(content = buf.getvalue(),content_type='image/png') then return response

Comment: yeah this time django can work normally but I still have the problem that the memory usage goes up when sending repeat requests. It seems that the recycling of the buffer don't cause this problem?